# Comparison of stopped sub- and supermartingales when the future is discounted

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Suppose we have a submartingale $X=\{X_t\}_t$ and a supermartingale $Y=\{Y_t\}_t$ which are adapted to the same filtration on a bounded set and have a common initial value $X_0=Y_0$. Suppose that $\tau^*_p$ is a stopping time that solves
$$
\max_{\tau}\  p\, \mathbb E[\delta^\tau X_{\tau}]+(1-p)\,\mathbb E[\delta^\tau Y_{\tau}]
$$ 
where $\delta\in(0,1)$ and maximization is over all stopping times that are measurable with respect to the filtration generated by the processes $X$ and $Y$. I want to prove or disprove that $$q>p\Rightarrow \tau^*_q\ge \tau^*_p$$

Intuitively, suppose an investor owns an asset and is uncertain about the process that governs its future value. He believes that with probability $p$ the value of the asset is governed by $X$ and with probability $1-p$ it is governed by $Y$. The statement I am trying to prove is that the investor will wait longer the more optimistic he is that the value will increase over time.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your particular stopping time rule does not seem to make decisions based on observations of the process, it chooses a deterministic $\tau^*$ based only on expectations.  So a sophisticated "stopping time" theorem is not needed. So, assuming $\tau^*$ is finite, then $E[\delta^{\tau^*} X_{\tau^*}]= \delta^{\tau^*}E[X_{\tau^*}] \geq \delta^{\tau^*}E[X_0]$. Similarly for $Y$, so your fact is true. It might not be true if you had a stopping rule that depended on the realizations of the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am indeed interested in a stopping time that is measurable with respect to the filtration generated by the processes X and Y, so it can depend on the process realizations. When saying "it might not be true", do you mean you have an argument for why the claim would not hold in general?